# jQuery animation stop weird output

Tags: jquery, animation

my issue is that Im animating a heart just + - width, height and left top, but it doesnt stop the animation, it doubles it, lick if i close and open again will do each step twice, and three times if three times closed and so on.

Is anoying as I have used the .stop(true, false) before with success but is not working with this animation, i tried to replace all -= and += for absolute values in a container div that is centered (as top left are different in orientation change) but didnt sloved it.

Also trying with a running variable and setting it to false and .clearQueue(). Also to put $('#Heart') as variable and call it allways as that but problem persists. If anyone could point me out why is this behaviour I will appreciatte it a lot.

```
function opened() {
    var Heart = $('#Heart');
    if (Pacemaker === 3) {
        $('#Heart').fadeOut(100, function () {
            $('#Div').fadeIn(100);
            Runner = false;
        });
    }
    if (Runner === true && Pacemaker < 3) {
        Heart.animate({width: '170px', height: '142px', left: '10px', top: '+=10px'}, 600,     function () {
            console.log('still');
            Heart.animate({width: '210px', height: '182px', left: '0px', top: '-=10px'}, 600, function () {
                console.log('still');
                Heart.animate({width: '170px', height: '142px', left: '10px', top: '+=10px'}, 600, function () {
                    console.log('still');
                    Heart.animate({width: '210px', height: '182px', left: '0px', top: '-=10px'}, 600, function () {
                        console.log('still');
                        Pacemaker++;
                        /*$('#Heart').stop(true, false); tried also putting it here*/

                        opened();        
                    });       
                });     
            });       
        });
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function closed() {
    $('#Heart').stop(true, false).css({display : 'block' });
    $('#Heart').clearQueue();
    Pacemaker = 0;   

}
```

Comment: And could you provide a live demo of this script running, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KBhdL/9/ strange but in the fiddle works correctly, cant share the real link as is work related, but behaviour there is different, so i guess the problem is not in the stop, what else could be affecting it?...

Comment: I don't know; that's where debugging comes in I'm afraid. At least you've ruled out one possibility! =)